# Network Image not showing in FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to display network image in FlatList.I know network image should be given width and height which I have given it

Here is my json

```
"templateview": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "category_name": "Anniversary",
                "template_name": "http://zedexeposter.fbmlive.com/public/template_images/BYXdptf45tRoXQNv.png",
                "deleted": "0",
                "created_at": "2020-03-23 12:27:10",
                "updated_at": "2020-03-24 11:38:02"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "category_name": "Birthday",
                "template_name": "http://zedexeposter.fbmlive.com/public/template_images/3Jkg5AAB2oR5VDz5.png",
                "deleted": "0",
                "created_at": "2020-03-23 12:48:29",
                "updated_at": "2020-03-24 11:38:20"
            }
        ]
```

Here is my code

```
<FlatList
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            data={state.data.templateview}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({item, index}) => {
              console.log(item.template_name);
              return (

                  <Image
                    source={{uri: item.template_name}}
                    style={StyleSheet.flatten([
                      styles.image,
                      {
                        borderColor: selectedImage === index ? '#000' : '#fff',
                      },
                    ])}
                  />

              );
            }}
          />
```

Here is my style

```
image: {
    width: width / 1.2,
    height: height / 2,
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
```

I also tried hardcoding width and height but same issue

The second image in the json won't display correctly.Instead it displays a black image. When I take just an Image component and pass the second image uri, it displays correctly but when I take it inside a `FlatList` the second image goes black. This issue happens only on Android. I tested on iOS simulator and it displays correctly. I have tested only on Android Lollipop and Marshmallow I don't have any android devices and the android emulator literally freezes my laptop so not testing on that. I also added `android:largeHeap="true"` in `AndroidManifest` to application tag. The image url is correct and I have tested and opened it inside various browsers and it works.

This only happens for horizontal scroll of FlatList and not for vertical scroll.